# Use entities from composer package in api platform

Tags: api-platform.com

As we use the entities in multiple projects we have required our entities via composer.
All the stuff that would normally be in the annotations I have written into a yaml file.
But I don't get any routes shown in the frontend or the swagger documentation.

I have found the following configuration: `api_platform.resource_class_directories`
But you have to set a directory there. I would not really like to have a hardcoded path like `vendor/my-company/my-entity-package/src/Entity`.

So how do I solve this issue?
Is there a magic variable in symfony like the `%kernel.project_dir%` which points to the vendor directory?
Did I forget to set some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by extending the classes of my composer package.

So in `api/src/Entity/Order.php` I have the following:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Company\ComposerPackage\Entity\Order as ComposerOrder;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order extends ComposerOrder
{
    /**
     * @var int The id of this order entity.
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

For some reason api-platform was not recognizing the id property and it's annotations so I had to copy it to the child class.

The entity in the composer package also needed a change for this to work:

```
namespace Company\ComposerPackage\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class Order
{
    // all properties are defined here including the @ORM, @Assert etc. annotations
}
```

I had to add the `@ORM\MappedSuperclass` annotation.

The `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotation also had to be done in the childclass for some reason. Also if you have additional configuration for the table e.g. table name or unique constraints these also have to be added to the child class.

Comment: did you tell doctrine about the entities?

Comment: All doctrine related configuration `@ORM\Table`, `@ORM\Entity`, `@ORM\Column`, etc. are in the parent class. But for no obvious reason some things like the id or the `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` need to be in the sub class otherwise they will not be applied

Comment: Were you able to generate a table schema without the  entities in App\Entity? My guess is that doctrine wasn't configured correctly so it didn't load your package entities and api-platform silently ignored your config because of the missing entities...

Comment: Yes the table schema is completely generated with all settings from the parent class